# How to use Option Pattern in side AutoMapper class?

Tags: .net-core, automapper

i would like to use Option Pattern in side AutoMapper class but it isn't workig
this is the startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
        }
```

this is the my AutoMapping

```
 public class AutoMapping : Profile
    {
        private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettings;
        public AutoMapping(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        {
            this._appSettings = appSettings;
            
                CreateMap<Hotel, HotelDTO>();
                CreateMap<HotelDTO, Hotel>().ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.AllowNull());
             
        }
    }
```

the mapping is workig well but the IOption gives me internal server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use dependency injection in your profile. Instead get your `IOptions` instance in the same place your getting your `IMapper` instance. Then, when you call `Map` you can use the overload where you send in the resolution context. For instance:

```cs
IMapper _mapper;
IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettings;

var hotel = new Hotel();
var hotelDto = _mapper.Map<HotelDTO>(hotel, ctx => {
    ctx.Items["appSettings"] = _appsettings;
})
```

Then you can use the corresponding overload in your profile:

```cs
CreateMap<Hotel, HotelDTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, prop, ctx) => {
        return ctx.Items["appSettings"];
    }));
```